# Memory leak when using std::shared_ptr to std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-leaks

I have an Image class :

```
class Image{

   public:

    Image()
    {
      vector_ptr = std::make_shared<std::vector<Feature>>(feature_vector);
    }

    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<Feature>> calculate_vector()
    {
      // iterates over a space of possible features, calling
      // vector_ptr->push_back(Feature(type, i, j, w, h, value))

      return vector_ptr;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<Feature>> get_vector()
    {
      return vector_ptr;
    }

    void clear_vector()
    {
      vector_ptr->clear();
    }

  private:
    std::vector<Feature> feature_vector;
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<Feature>> vector_ptr;
};
```

Where Feature is given by :

```
struct Feature
{
    Feature(int type, int i, int j, int w, int h, double value);
    void print();

    int type;

    int i, j;
    int w, h;

    double value;
};
```

But after successively calling calculate_vector(), and then clear_vector(), htop indicates there is a memory leak.

How do I resolve this problem?  (The feature vector is very large)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vector_ptr` is a copy of `feature_vector`, it isn't a shared wrapper around it. So you'd need to call `feature_vector.clear();` as well if you wanted to free up its memory.

Comment: So, make_shared creates a copy of the object given to it?

Comment: then, the feature_vector is redundant if I only manipulate the vector_ptr within the class?

Comment: @Kalessar: make_shared creates a new object. As it is it's calling the vector copy constructor. You should be able to use `std::move` to invoke the move constructor. But yes, from the code above it appears that `feature_vector` is redundant.